# I am shown the 10K users' "edit tags" link but it doesn't work

Tags: bug, tags, design, 10k-tools

I was looking at [Drupal Blocks Custom Display Naming Convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573147/drupal-blocks-custom-display-naming-convention) and I noticed that hovering the mouse to the right of the tags, I saw the "edit tags" link only 10K users see. (My reputation is 9915.)

The link doesn't work: If I click on it, nothing happens.

> [image: screenshot]